# Añadir clase bg-primary de bootstrap a un <tr> de manera dinamica? MVC

Tags: c#, bootstrap, mvc

Es decir tengo una tabla que se llena con un foreach en `MVC`.
Lo que quiero hacer es colorear toda una fila si la Cantidad Disponible es menor que la cantidad Minima de no ser asi no colorear las filas, por este motivo no me sirve  añadir la `class="bg-primary"` de manera estatica tiene que ser dinamico creo.
Gracias por la ayuda.
[image: Cuerpo de la tabla]

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor en las partes de las preguntas donde es código garegarlo como tal y aplicar {} para mejor redacción y se mas fácil a la comunidad ayudar.  Visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pudes hacer es agregar una condicion en tu `tr` si se cumple agregas la `clase` en caso contrario una cadena vacia.

Ejemplo:

```
<tr class="@((item.CantidadDisponible<item.CantidadMinima) ? "bg-primary" : "")" >
```

Comment: Genial muchisimas gracias.  necesito empezar a aprender a usar las condicionales dentro  del tr gracias.